# Why does a nearby switch turn off when I use a switch I just replaced?

Tags: electrical

I recently replaced a dimmer switch with regular switch. The problem now is, whenever I turn the lights off, the electrical switch near by switches off as well. (which it never did before).

The box has 2 black wires and 1 red wire and 2 green wires which is screwed into the box. (the two green wires I have not touched at all)

Comment: You say a nearby switch turns off, but what I think you mean is that the circuit it controls goes dead. Is that right? Please provide more detail about your wiring in your post.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably:

The "always hot"  feeding power to both switches was confused with the "switched hot" and is now feeding the second switch from the first switch's switched hot, rather than the always hot to the box.

Answer (score 0):

The hot jumper for the second switch is on the wrong side of the switch that you are turning off. You have 3 wires 2 black and a red going to the switch if I read it correctly. I would be moving them around to get the correct combination one wire is the hot and should go to both switches. The good thing is with these 3 wires moving them with the power off then testing you can not hurt anything because when the switch is in the on position all 3 are connected together. If there is a black on either side of the switch swap both blacks or just move the read to the other side will probably fix it as a first guess without knowing how they are connected.